# Method for Finding Random Vector3 Perpendicular to the original

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game where you can collect resources from a planet system and I want to break up the planets into multiple pieces and have them slowly drift apart. The best way I can think to do this is to instantiate a few prefabs as "chunks of planet" and have them drift apart on a similar orbit/ velocity to the planet originally. what I need is a way to randomly get a vector direction perpendicular to the current velocity to push them away from each other. I already know trhat i need another to cross product im just wondering if there is a way to get a random one out of the infinite.
Thanks for the help in advance :)
My Current workaround is this

```
            GameObject CurrentAsteroid = Instantiate(AsteroidPrefab);
            AstroPhysics CurrentAsteroidAP = CurrentAsteroid.GetComponent<AstroPhysics>();
            
            Vector3 A = CurrentAsteroidAP.GetVelocityUnity();
            Vector3 n = new Vector3(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f),
                                    Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f),
                                    Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));
            Vector3 AdditionalMovement = (A - (Vector3.Dot(A, n) * n)).normalized;
            CurrentAsteroidAP.SetVelocity(this.GetComponent<AstroPhysics>().GetVelocityUnity() + AdditionalMovement);
```

Comment: Why workaround? What you are doing is find a generally random vector and then finding one perpendicluar to both the random one and your original vector. That's not that many calculations, so it is likely a solid solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random vector and use [Orthonormalize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.OrthoNormalize.html) to make it orthogonal:

```
// As an extension method...
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Vector3 RandomOrthogonal(this Vector3 input)
    {
        Vector3 output = Random.onUnitSphere;
        Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref input, ref output);
        return output;
    }
}

// And you can use it like the following:
Vector3 randomMagnitude = Random.value * A.magnitude;
Vector3 randomOrthogonalOfA = A.RandomOrthogonal() * randomMagnitude;


// ... Or just make it a static method:

public class WhateverClassName
{
    public static Vector3 RandomOrthogonal(Vector3 input)
    {
        Vector3 output = Random.onUnitSphere;
        Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref input, ref output);
        return output;
    }
}

// And you can use it like the following:
Vector3 randomMagnitude = Random.value * A.magnitude;
Vector3 randomOrthogonalOfA = WhateverClassName.RandomOrthogonal(A) 
        * randomMagnitude;
```